# PHP start .bat then redirect

Tags: php, cmd

I have this script to start a bat file, and it does but after it starts it just crashes the web page, I need the script to redirect the user to a done page after the .bat has started...

```
<?php

exec('c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\VGBR\steamapps\common\GarrysModDS\Start.bat');

?>

<?php
$var="Start";
echo "Starting...";
echo $var;
header("Location: done.php");
exit;
?>
```

This is what I've got so far...

Comment: Pretty sure you can't have the space or echo when you want to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that when you use `echo` function PHP **HAVE** to send headers to the client, so any subsequent header will **NOT** be sent.

To correct that either you remove the `echoes` (as client won't see them) or you remove the `header()` and add a JavaScript that does the redirect.

**Edit:**
As *Dave Chen* stated, you **shouldn't** have that whitespace between the script outside the `<?PHP` tag as it is sent to the client (again, with headers).

To do what you are asking, do the script that way :

```
<?php
exec('c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\VGBR\steamapps\common\GarrysModDS\Start.bat > NUL');

header('Location: /done.php');
die();
?>
```

**EDIT 2**
If the PHP keeps hanging, it is because it is waiting that .bat app to return something. In that case, check the following StackOverflow questions:
[php exec command (or similar) to not wait for result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819398/php-exec-command-or-similar-to-not-wait-for-result)
[Running a PHP "exec()" in the background on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692263/running-a-php-exec-in-the-background-on-windows)

Comment: I did that, it opens it but indefinitely stays open in a tab... I need the tab to redirect after its done

Comment: I editted the code. Try it now. If it doesn't works, it probably means that the exec keeps running and php is waiting for it to return something before continuing

Comment: In that case, check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819398/php-exec-command-or-similar-to-not-wait-for-result

Comment: How do I do thhat? I'm new to PHP

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692263/running-a-php-exec-in-the-background-on-windows says `exec('c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\VGBR\steamapps\common\GarrysModDS\Start.bat > NUL');`

Comment: Editted my answer with new link and changed code. Try and tell me if it works

Comment: Try `$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->Run('c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\VGBR\steamapps\common\GarrysModDS\Start.bat', 0, false);`

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Access\repository\HT2\WH\www.voltzgaming.com\public_html\Admin\Server\Start\VGBR\Start.php on line 17

Comment: I don't really know what your .bat file does nor your system specifications, that makes it a bit hard. Can you add an `echo` on your `.bat` ? P.S: that COM error means that your PHP doesn't support the windows COM

Comment: xampp with windows server 2008

Comment: the cmd is a scrds console

Comment: Try the popen approach `pclose(popen('start /B C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\VGBR\steamapps\common\GarrysModDS\Start.bat', 'r'));`

Comment: ( use the above code instead of the `exec()`. Tell me if it works )