# START a proccess in background in WINDOWS

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, background-process, putty

I have a problem running a command from a `PHP` script. The command I am trying to run is

`echo y | plink -ssh -N -D 9999 admin@1.2.3.4 -pw admin -v`

The thing is that the command runs but the script freezes until the execution of `plink` command, which I don't want. I also tried (running in background) this :

`START /MIN "cmd.exe" /C "plink -ssh -N -D 9999 admin@1.2.3.4 -pw admin"`

and I see minimized `plink` running, and as soon as I close it, the script continues.

I also tried:

`START /B /MIN "cmd.exe" /C "plink -ssh -N -D 9999 admin@1.2.3.4 -pw admin"`

and it does the same thing, but is showing the output in the PHP script.

this is the function :

```
function create_tunnel($ip,$user,$pass,$port)
{
    exec('START /min cmd /c "echo y | plink -ssh -N -D '.$port.' '.$user.'@'.$ip.' -pw '.$pass.' -v" > nul');
}
```

What must I do to run this command and let the PHP script continue execution? In linux this would be very simple, I would just use `screen` command.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `START /B`?

Comment: Have you checked if there is no ghost process of plink?

Comment: @PanamaJack yes, just ouput the command and waits ... Paul no there is no ghost process

Comment: If I understand, you want to execute the batch and php script continue his other jobs? php script are waiting plink? Or maybe it's the opposite?

Comment: Have you tried `START "" /MIN "cmd.exe /C plink -ssh -N -D 9999 admin@1.2.3.4 -pw admin"` (also with `/B`)?

Comment: yes, still waitining ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running a PHP "exec()" in the background on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692263/running-a-php-exec-in-the-background-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Try Symfony [Process](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) component:

```
$process = new Process('ls -lsa');
$process->start();

while ($process->isRunning()) {
    // waiting for process to finish
}

echo $process->getOutput();
```

Comment: do i  need to inculde a special class or something? or it is in PHP libraries? also i am using WINDOWS if i was in LINUX i would just use screen

Comment: It's a tiny standalone part of well known php framework Symfony. It's crossplatform, obviously, and well tested. You can install it via Composer or download from official repo, then include `vendor/autoload.php` file in your's script and it will be ready for usage.

Comment: Also, you can peep at it's implementation for revealing details of async command execution. There `popen` php function used instead of just `exec`, afaik.

Comment: `pclose(popen('START /b /min  cmd /c "echo y | plink -ssh -N -D '.$port.' '.$user.'@'.$ip.' -pw '.$pass.' -v" > nul',"r"));` ??? this?? apparently works ... don't know why ...

Comment: `popen` just opens started process handle. `exec` also waits for process output, so, it blocks script until started process terminates. in order to retrive executed process output when using `popen` you must just read it as from regular file with `fread`, manually. So, basically, `exec` internally uses `popen` and then waits for output.