# Asynchronously start process from script started from php

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, service, cmd

I have Apache server on my windows machine.

From PHP script I start `.bat` file using exec command(synchronously!).

From my batch script I run another executable(`WinDBG`). I run it asynchronously(using `cmd` start command) wait some time and kill if it is still running.

If I run .bat script from `cmd` it works as planned(asynchronously).
But if script is started from PHP `exec` command "start" works synchronously. And it is the same code.

I think that the problem is that PHP script run as a windows service. And therefore start work synchronously.

I should start `WinDBG` asynchronously to have ability terminate it

Comment: PHP won't return until the standard output handle (and perhaps the standard error handle?) is closed.  That won't happen so long as a descendant process exists, unless you take steps to prevent the handle from being inherited or to explicitly close it.  You could try redirecting the output to NUL, as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/7693202/886887, but I'm [no longer sure that works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36091748/how-do-i-use-the-start-command-without-inheriting-handles-in-the-child-process).

Comment: Harry Johnston, the thing is that I do not want batch script started from php to run asynk. I want start process from my batch file and do not wait for it to terminate

Comment: Are you sure that it is the batch file that is waiting and not PHP?  That would only happen if the application failed to start properly, perhaps because of a missing DLL dependency or a problem with the permissions on the executable.